# Layout weight changes when nested JPanels are used with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

My problem is similar to this: [Nested JPanel with GridBagLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236551/nested-jpanel-with-gridbaglayout).

Basically, when a `JPanel` is nested into a `JPanel` in a frame using `GridBagLayout`, the weight of the `GridBagLayout` changes automatically. Is there a way to fix the weight of `GridBagLayout` so that it does not change no matter what is nested into it?

Comment: These type of questions almost always require that you, the original poster, create and post your [mcve]. Please read the link -- this is not a full code dump but rather a minimal example program, one that we can compile and run unchanged, and that demonstrates your problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

Set the weight to 0 like in the tutorial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

If you want to have the consistant size of row/column you must set weight 0 for all components in this row/column.

You can also try setting nested JPanel size manually, using
yourpanel.setSize(valueX, valueY);